# Error while trying to add a custom cell into table view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode9

I'm trying to add a custom cell into my tableview

This what I configured for custom **CustomProfileView.xib** file

[image]

**Main.storyboard**

[image]

I kept getting

> Use of undeclared type 'CustomProfileCell'

This my entire code

```
//
//  FirstViewController.swift
//  tabbed
//
//  Created by Ben Heng on 7/18/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 LR Web Design. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileTableView: UITableView!

    var profileArray = [Profile]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        profileTableView.delegate = self
        profileTableView.dataSource = self
        profileTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ProfileCell",bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomProfileCell")

        retrieveProfiles()

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return profileArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomProfileCell

        cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: profileArray[indexPath.row].profileImage)
        cell.profileName.text = profileArray[indexPath.row].name
        cell.deviceCount.text = profileArray[indexPath.row].deviceCount

        return (cell)
    }



    func retrieveProfiles() {

        let p1 = Profile()
        p1.name = "John"
        p1.deviceCount = "10"
        p1.profileImage = "john"
        profileArray.append(p1)

        let p2 = Profile()
        p2.name = "Jane"
        p2.deviceCount = "5"
        p2.profileImage = "jane"
        profileArray.append(p2)

        let p3 = Profile()
        p3.name = "Andrew"
        p3.deviceCount = "4"
        p3.profileImage = "andrew"
        profileArray.append(p3)

        self.profileTableView.reloadData()


    }

}
```

Comment: forCellReuseIdentifier should be "customProfileCell", not "CustomProfileCell"

Comment: on this line `profileTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ProfileCell",bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "customProfileCell")` ?

Comment: I've tried that I got the same error.

Comment: your identifier `customProfileCell`, not `ProfileCell`. ProfileCell is your class name

Comment: You mean `nibName` ? I'm confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your swift the name `CustomProfileViewCell`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomProfileViewCell
```

//

```
profileTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomProfileViewCell",bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "customProfileCell")
```

Comment: Ahh I think you found my mistake.. Can you share how you spot that ? Please

Comment: When creating a class by default the name **CustomProfileViewCell.swift** implies that the class name is  **CustomProfileViewCell** , i looked to your image project hierarchy , also you should use same identifier in register and dequeue

Comment: @kyo I attatched the register & dequeue lines in answer

Comment: Please see the latest screenshot of what I have on above comment.

Comment: copy the first line in answer and replace it inside **cellForRowAt**  ,, copy the second and replace the register line in **viewDidLoad**

Comment: Please have a look at the latest screenshot !

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623246-reuseidentifier) first, it explains how `reuseIdentifier` work and what it means.

First of all your nib name is `CustomProfileViewCell`, but you're registering nib with `ProfileCell` name.

Second error is that you're using `ProfileCell` identifier in storyboard, that should be same as your defined identifier which is - `customProfileCell`.

Your cell registration should looks like this

```
profileTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomProfileViewCell",bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "customProfileCell")
```

and then you want to use it as here:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomProfileViewCell
```

Comment: nib name is also **CustomProfileViewCell** not **CustomProfileCell**

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help. I fixed of the issues you pointed out.

Comment: I got this `Cannot convert return expression of type 'CustomProfileCell' to return type 'UITableViewCell'` Is it related ?

Comment: cast is to **as! CustomProfileViewCell**

Comment: Change it to this  **let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomProfileViewCell**

Comment: You answered my question.  I will ask a separate question. You can answer there in stead. I don't wanna confuse poeple.